# @font-face doesn't work ONLY on smartphone Facebook App

Tags: android, css, facebook, fonts, font-face

It's a strange problem: the title *"Vivi Piccante"* uses a custom font that works fine in all devices and browsers (where i tested it), but it doesn't work only on android **smartphone facebook app**. The android smartphone Fb app ignores all font-face declarations. It's not an *android* problem because on same device i try to open same url on chrome and fonts works fine.

Is it my fault or a fb app problem? If it's my fault, is there a way to fix this problem?

- Tablet Android - Facebook App - OK
- Tablet Android - Browsers - OK
- **Smartphone Android - Facebook App - FAIL**
- Smartphone Android - Browsers - OK
- Desktop Win10 - Chrome/Edge/Firefox - OK

**CSS:**

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'bellotabold_italic';
src: url('/App_Style/fonts/Bellota/BellotaBoldItalicwebfont.eot');
src: url('/App_Style/fonts/Bellota/BellotaBoldItalicwebfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/App_Style/fonts/Bellota/BellotaBoldItalicwebfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/App_Style/fonts/Bellota/BellotaBoldItalicwebfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/App_Style/fonts/Bellota/BellotaBoldItalicwebfont.svg#bellotabold_italic') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}
```

**Screenshot test:**
[image]

Comment: Android™ devices have a very limited range of default fonts, even a .pdf viewer recommends downloading further fonts, which any user is free to do.  The only drawback is good fonts seem to occupy a lot of memory, which is limited since most Android decices don't have hard drives.

Comment: remove those EOT and SVG resources. They're no longer supported (eot is necessary only for IE8 and below, which were abandoned in January 2016 by Microsoft) and the SVG font format was discontinued quite a while before that. Also remove those TTF and OTF sources, they're universally installable fonts, which older browsers that respect font-embedding bits can easily reject. For modern browsers, on all platforms, [you just need WOFF, and that's it](http://caniuse.com/#search=woff). Reduce your complexity here, and then see if you still have the same problem.